# How to test LazyInitializationExceptions?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-test

I have some code which (in production):

- In one thread, primes a cache with data from the db
- In another thread, grabs the data from the cache, and starts iterating it's properties.

This threw a `LazyInitializationException`.

While I know how to fix the problem, I want to get a test around this.  However I can't figure out how to recreate the exception in the correct part of the test.

I have to prime the DB with some test data, therefore my test is annotated with `@Transactional`.  Failing to do so causes the set-up to fail with... you guessed it... `LazyInitializationException`.

Here's my current test:

```
@Transactional
public class UpdateCachedMarketPricingActionTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UpdateCachedMarketPricingAction action;

    @Autowired
    private PopulateMarketCachesTask populateMarketCachesTask;

    @Test @SneakyThrows
    public void updatesCachedValues()
    {

        // Populate the cache from a different thread, as this is how it happens in real life
        Thread updater = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateMarketCachesTask.populateCaches();
            }
        });
        updater.start();
        updater.join();

             updateMessage = {...} //ommitted 

        action.processInstrumentUpdate(updateMessage);
    }
```

So, I'm priming my cache in a separate thread, to try to get it outside of the current `@Transaction` scope.  Additionally, I'm also calling `entityManager.detatch(entity)` inside the cache primer, to try to ensure that the entities that exist within the cache can't lazy-load their collections.

However, the test passes... no exception is thrown.

How can I forcibly get an entity to a state that when I next try to iterate it's collections, it will throw the `LazyInitializationException`?

Comment: Can't you mock any parts of that? It will be much easier to reproduce

Comment: Not really... it defeats the purpose of the test.  I'm trying to test specific behaviour of these moving parts, to prevent a bug that occurred in production.  Mocking away the key elements makes the test easier to write, but pointless.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see why? You know that with a mock you can do (using mockito at least) `when(mock.next()).thenReturn().thenReturn().thenThrow()`, right? And if you grab the result of `when()` you can chain an arbitrary numbers of `.thenReturn()` before `.thenThrow()`. I see no incompatibility. You can even emulate sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the transactions for each operation are committed, independent of each other. Annotating your test method or test class with `@Tranactional` leaves the *current* test transaction open and then rolls it back after execution of the entire test.

So one option is to do something like the following:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


@Test
public void example() {
    new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            // add your code here...
        }
    });
}
```

You could invoke your first operation in its own callback, and then invoke the second operation in a different callback. Then, when you access Hibernate or JPA entities after the callbacks, the entities will no longer be attached to the current unit of work (e.g., Hibernate `Session`). Consequently, accessing a lazy collection or field at that point would result in a `LazyInitializationException`.

Regards,

Sam

p.s. please note that this technique will naturally leave changes committed to your database. So if you need to clean up that modified state, consider doing so manually in an `@AfterTransaction` method.